# Understanding of Static variables across cluster environment

Tags: java

We have been trying to implement some sort of Cache mechanism where we are trying to render  list of Objects through a plugin. These list of values are then held in a concurrent hash map within a class . We are creating a Instance of the class when required through UI and referring to this cache to display the list of values. The cache is refreshed either via online button or  a overnight job(also program loads cache if empty/null) .

This was working okay until we were in single cluster. As we moved to cluster environment and when we added a new/amend Objects on other system(interacted via plugin), the list is refreshed only on batch-cum-online server and the other cluster is out of sync. This issue is happening intermittently and now having a doubt on static variables. Is static variables created one each for separate jvms? If so, is it synchronized on some way. Also any hint on why this is intermittent(we doubted if there was a out of cluster during batch run - but not sure) .

private static Map _cache = new ConcurrentHashMap(16, 0.75, 1)

java version 1.6

using IBM WAS server

Answer (score 1):

Of course your static variable only live and meaningful inside the JVM it's created.

To address this issue, you can trick by sending update request to all other server when your batch sync complete.

But the formal way is to separate your cache storage into a standalone server (like redis) instead of a static variable

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you please help on the method you mentioned 'sending update request to all other server when your batch sync complete' . Can you please pass some reference to this

Comment: Agree with above and we reverted this design. The issue was happening because though URL was telling server server cluster 1 internally it was still pointing to server cluster 2.